# Unity: Initializing smoke Prefab via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use a smoke prefab (free asset from Unity asset store). When I add the prefab directly into the game scene, the prefab works:
[image: The prefab]

But when I create the following script to initialize the same prefab (inside a game object), nothing happens:

```
class Smoke1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(myPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }


}
```

My game scene:
[image: The scene and script]

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);`. This will spawn the prefab in the center of the scene. If it works, then it means you're doing something weird with the position and rotation of the object upon instantiation.

Comment: blastervla is right. Also check where the "Smoke1" instance is located - you use it's position to create the myPrefab instance. When you run the game, you can double-click the "GameObject" in the scene-tree that instantiates the smoke particle system, which should focus the scene-editor on the "GameObject" where the smoke instance should be located as well.